# Catching multiple exceptions / status codes with @app.errorhandler

Tags: flask

If I want to catch an exception and a status code with `@app.errorhandler`, what's the best way to do this?  I notice you can put the decorator twice like this:

```py
class BadRequestError(Exception):
    pass

@app.errorhandler(400)
@app.errorhandler(BadRequestError)
def serve_400_error(error: Exception) -> Response:
    return client_error_page(400)
```

But it acts a bit funky making me wonder if this is best practice.  For example, swapping the 2 decorators results in a Mypy error, as does changing the var name `error` to `_`.